# Remove/Avoid duplicates from combined list of items

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an `exsl:node-set` with an array of items that I used as a *lookup table* to display the *Location* of from another *unique list* that I have built from the XML document itself. The lookup works fine, however, I would like to be able to remove duplicates form the resulting data set.

The following image illustrates the problem.

[image]

**XML Document**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="default.xsl"?>
<TestResults>
    <Result>
        <TestID>1001</TestID>
        <ResultValue>2.5</ResultValue>
        <InstrumentID>503||1</InstrumentID>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <TestID>1002</TestID>
        <ResultValue>6.3</ResultValue>
        <InstrumentID>503||1</InstrumentID>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <TestID>1003</TestID>
        <ResultValue>11</ResultValue>
        <InstrumentID>342||1</InstrumentID>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <TestID>1004</TestID>
        <ResultValue>201</ResultValue>
        <InstrumentID>342||1</InstrumentID>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <TestID>1005</TestID>
        <ResultValue>85</ResultValue>
        <InstrumentID>731||1</InstrumentID>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <TestID>1006</TestID>
        <ResultValue>33.6</ResultValue>
        <InstrumentID>334||1</InstrumentID>
    </Result>
  </TestResults>
```

**XLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <!-- INSTRUMENTS PER SITE ARRAY -->
    <xsl:variable name="instruments-site">
        <instrument ID='334||3'>Laboratory 1</instrument>
        <instrument ID='342||1'>Laboratory 1</instrument>
        <instrument ID='342||2'>Laboratory 1</instrument>
        <instrument ID='503||1'>Laboratory 1</instrument>
        <instrument ID='503||2'>Laboratory 1</instrument>
        <instrument ID='503||3'>Laboratory 2</instrument>
        <instrument ID='503||4'>Laboratory 2</instrument>
        <instrument ID='731||1'>Laboratory 2</instrument>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="list-instruments-site" select="exsl:node-set($instruments-site)" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>

    <!-- INSTRUMENT LIST-->
    <xsl:key name="key-instruments" match="/TestResults/Result" use="InstrumentID"/>
    <xsl:key name="key-instruments-list" match="/TestResults/Result/InstrumentID" use="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="unique-instruments-list" select="//TestResults/Result/InstrumentID[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-instruments-list', .)[1])]"/> 
    
    <xsl:variable name="unique-location-list" select="$list-instruments-site/instrument[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-instruments-list', .)[1])]"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/TestResults">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test Document</title>
            </head>
            <body>     
                <h2>Instruments</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$unique-instruments-list" mode="instr-locations" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="instr-locations" match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**What I have tried**

1. I tried building a third *unique list* from using the `$unique-location-list` like this:

```xml
    <xsl:variable name="unique-location-list" select="$list-instruments-site/instrument[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-instruments-list', .)[1])]"/>
```

2. I have also tried using `preceding-sibling` on the `instr-locations` template, like this:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="previous" select="preceding-sibling::$list-instruments-site/instrument" />
<xsl:if test="$previous != current()">
  <xsl:value-of select="$list-instruments-site/instrument[@ID=current()]" />
</xsl:if>
```

I appreciate the help in advance. Keep in mind that the solution has to be in XSLT 1.0.

**Desired HTML output**

I expect something similar to this as HTML output, answering @martinhonnen's comment.

```html
<ul>
 <li>Laboratorio 1</li>
 <li>Laboratorio 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So what is the desired output HTML? And does the Apache Java namespace indicate you are using Xalan? It has EXSLT extensions for unique/distinct values I think.

Comment: Hey Martin. I added the expected HTML output. No, i am not using Xalan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be able to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:variable name="labs">
    <lab name="Laboratory 1">
        <instrument ID="334||3"/>
        <instrument ID="342||1"/>
        <instrument ID="342||2"/>
        <instrument ID="503||1"/>
        <instrument ID="503||2"/>
     </lab>
    <lab name="Laboratory 2">
        <instrument ID="503||3"/>
        <instrument ID="503||4"/>
        <instrument ID="731||1"/>
    </lab>
</xsl:variable>
    
<xsl:template match="/TestResults">
    <xsl:variable name="instrumentIDs" select="Result/InstrumentID" />
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($labs)/lab[instrument/@ID = $instrumentIDs]">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" /><br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```